# Element update for Java Util List

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList for Patients in little hospital system and need to write a method to update the patient information. This method should take an integer called "id", match this id with all id's in Patient ArrayList and change some information in that object. How can I iterate this list? Thanks.

This is my Patient Class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Patient {
    String strName,strSurname,strAddress,strDepartment,strGender;
    int iId,iClass,iDob;
    List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    long longTel;
    boolean boolAllergy,boolChronicDisease,boolRegularMedicine;

    public boolean isBoolAllergy() {
        return boolAllergy;
    }
    public void setBoolAllergy(boolean boolAllergy) {
        this.boolAllergy = boolAllergy;
    }
    public boolean isBoolChronicDisease() {
        return boolChronicDisease;
    }
    public void setBoolChronicDisease(boolean boolChronicDisease) {
        this.boolChronicDisease = boolChronicDisease;
    }
    public boolean isBoolRegularMedicine() {
        return boolRegularMedicine;
    }
    public void setBoolRegularMedicine(boolean boolRegularMedicine) {
        this.boolRegularMedicine = boolRegularMedicine;
    }
    public String getStrName() {
        return strName;
    }
    public void setStrName(String strName) {
        this.strName = strName;
    }
    public String getStrSurname() {
        return strSurname;
    }
    public void setStrSurname(String strSurname) {
        this.strSurname = strSurname;
    }
    public String getStrAddress() {
        return strAddress;
    }
    public void setStrAddress(String strAddress) {
        this.strAddress = strAddress;
    }
    public String getStrDepartment() {
        return strDepartment;
    }
    public void setStrDepartment(String strDepartment) {
        this.strDepartment = strDepartment;
    }
    public int getiId() {
        return iId;
    }
    public void setiId(int iId) {
        this.iId = iId;
    }
    public long getlongTel() {
        return longTel;
    }
    public void setiTel(long iTel) {
        this.longTel = iTel;
    }
    public int getiClass() {
        return iClass;
    }
    public void setiClass(int iClass) {
        this.iClass = iClass;
    }
    public int getiDob() {
        return iDob;
    }
    public void setiDob(int iDob) {
        this.iDob = iDob;
    }
    public String getStrGender() {
        return strGender;
    }
    public void setStrGender(String strGender) {
        this.strGender = strGender;
    }
    public void Details() {
        System.out.println("*********************************");
        System.out.println("Patient Id: " + getiId());
        System.out.println("Name: " + getStrName() + " Surname: " + getStrSurname());
        System.out.println("Address: " + getStrAddress() + " Department: " + getStrDepartment() + " Gender: " + getStrGender());
        System.out.println("Class: " + getiClass() + " Date of birth: " + getiDob() + " Tel: " + getlongTel());
        System.out.println("Chronical Disease? " + isBoolChronicDisease());
        System.out.println("Any Allergy? " + isBoolAllergy());
        System.out.println("Using regular drugs?" + isBoolRegularMedicine());
        System.out.println("*********************************");
    }
}
```

And this is the main class that uses Patient class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

    static List<Doctor> listDoctors = new ArrayList<Doctor>();
    static List<Nurse> listNurses = new ArrayList<Nurse>();
    static List<Patient> listPatients = new ArrayList<Patient>();
    static String strUserName = "admin";
    static String strPass = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int iChoice;
        boolean exit = false;
        boolean boolAccess = Login();
        if (boolAccess) {
         while(!exit) {
            iChoice = Menu();
            switch(iChoice) {
                case 1:
                    AddDoctor();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    AddNurse();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    AddPatient();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    ListDoctors();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    ListNurses();
                    break;
                case 6:
                    ListPatients();
                    break;
                case 8:
                    ChangeUserName();
                    break;
                case 9:
                    ChangePass();
                    break;
                    //Hastalığa göre hastalar listelenecek
                    //Kronik hastlalıkları olan hastalar listelenecek
                    //Sigortasını yatırmayan hastalar listelenecek
                    //delete ve update olayları
                    //Hastaneye sevkedilen hastalar listelenecek
                    //Yatılı kalan hastalar listelensin
                    //Raporlu olan entryler listelenecek
                    //Kayıt girilirken eğer hasta ismi ilk defa giriliyorsa önce hasta kaydı yapın diye uyarı cıkacak
                case 15:
                    exit = true;
                    break;
            }
          }
       }
    }

    private static void ChangeUserName() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(Login()) {
            System.out.println("Enter new User Name:");
            strUserName = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Saved..");
        }
    }

    private static void ChangePass() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        if(Login()) {
            System.out.println("Enter new Password:");
            strPass = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Saved..");
        }
    }

    private static void ListNurses() {
        Iterator<Nurse> it = listNurses.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Nurse nur = (Nurse) it.next();
            nur.Details();
        }
    }

    private static void ListPatients() {
        Iterator<Patient> it = listPatients.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Patient patient = (Patient) it.next();
            patient.Details();
        }
    }

    public static boolean Login() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Username: ");
        if(strUserName.contentEquals(scan.next())) {
            System.out.println("Enter Password:");
            if(strPass.contentEquals(scan.next())) {
                return true;
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong password");   
                return Login();
            }
        System.out.println("Wrong user name");
        return Login();
    }

    public static int Menu() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Choose one of the following order:");
        System.out.println("1.Enter new Doctor");
        System.out.println("2.Enter new Nurse");
        System.out.println("3.Enter new Patient");
        System.out.println("4.List all doctors");
        System.out.println("5.List all nurses");
        System.out.println("6.List all patients");
        System.out.println("8.Change user name");
        System.out.println("9.Change password");
        System.out.println("15.Exit");

        return scan.nextInt();
    }

    private static void ListDoctors() {
        Iterator<Doctor> it = listDoctors.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Doctor doc = (Doctor) it.next();
            doc.Details();
        }
    }

    private static void AddDoctor() {
        Doctor doctor;
        String strName,strSurname,strSpeciality;
        int iSSN;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        strName=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter surname:");
        strSurname = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter speciality");
        strSpeciality = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter SSN");
        iSSN = scan.nextInt();

        doctor = new Doctor(strName,strSurname,strSpeciality,iSSN);
        listDoctors.add(doctor);

        System.out.println("Saved..");
    }

    private static void AddNurse() {
        Nurse nurse;
        String strName,strSurname;
        int iSSN;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        strName=scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter surname:");
        strSurname = scan.next();
        System.out.println("Enter SSN");
        iSSN = scan.nextInt();

        nurse = new Nurse(strName,strSurname,iSSN);
        listNurses.add(nurse);

        System.out.println("Saved..");
    }

    private static void AddPatient() {

        Patient patient = new Patient();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter name:");
        patient.setStrName(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter surname:");
        patient.setStrSurname(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter date of birth(DDMMYYYY)");
        patient.setiDob(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter address:");
        patient.setStrAddress(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter department:");
        patient.setStrDepartment(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter gender:");
        patient.setStrGender(scan.next());
        System.out.println("Enter Telephone number:");
        patient.setiTel(scan.nextLong());
        System.out.println("Enter id:");
        patient.setiId(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter class:");
        patient.setiClass(scan.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Does patient have any chronical disease? (Y/N)");
        if(scan.next().contentEquals("Y"))
            patient.setBoolChronicDisease(true);
        else
            patient.setBoolChronicDisease(false);
        System.out.println("Does patient use any regular drugs? (Y/N)");
        if(scan.next().contentEquals("Y"))
            patient.setBoolRegularMedicine(true);
        else
            patient.setBoolRegularMedicine(false);
        System.out.println("Does patient have any allergies?");
        if(scan.next().contentEquals("Y"))
            patient.setBoolAllergy(true);
        else
            patient.setBoolAllergy(false);

        listPatients.add(patient);
    }

    private static void SearchPatientById(int id) {
        Iterator<Patient> it = listPatients.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            Patient patient = (Patient) it.next();
            if(it.next().getiId() == id)
                patient.Details();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I search a spesific object in Patient ArrayList and change its attribute, (i.e. Telephone number)

Comment: What is not working in this?

Comment: @Joe Please do not add the homework tag to questions as it is obsolete. Refer to the tag wiki for more information.

Comment: Thanks, sorry didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a slight modification your searchPatientById can return the found patient object:

```
private static Patient searchPatientById(int id) {
    Iterator<Patient> it = listPatients.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        Patient patient = (Patient) it.next();
        if(patient.getiId() == id)
            return patient;
    }
    // if not found return null
    return null;
}
```

Note that I remove your double call to `next()`
That way, you can do something like

```
Patient foundPatient = searchPatientById(idToFind);
if (foundPatient != null) {
    foundPatient.setBoolAllergy(patientsAllergyState);
} else {
    // whatever you need to do if the patient cannot be found
}
```

Also note that in Java it's not common to encode the variable type into the variable names, but there's a universally followed [naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)